# Where can you find the cheapest beer at Stockholm-Arlanda Airport?

Tags: airports, food-and-drink, factoids, alcohol, arn

The beer is super expensive at Stockholm-Arlanda Airport, usually around 100-120:- (10-12€) for a 50 cl lager at any bar or restaurant. As a Swede I find this outrageous as a beer in the alco shop is 10:- (1€).

The airport actually <strike>has</strike> had [a page](https://www.swedavia.com/arlanda/food-for-under-sek-100-at-stockholm-arlanda/) listing cheap foods, but the drinks are still expensive at these places.

Is there any place at Arlanda with cheap beer?

---

*Because of Swedish laws you are not permitted to drink your own alcohol at the airport.*

Comment: I voted to close this question as it is offtopic, a shopping question and is not fit for this site.

Comment: @Daniil there are plenty of questions like this one?

Comment: @Daniil the prohibition on shopping questions is in part based on the argument that "technology moves so rapidly that the best shopping recommendations will be utterly obsolete within a year"; a point that is of limited applicability to [Travel.SE].  Furthermore, the examples offered in support of the prohibition are all solicitations for opinions in the service of making a *subjective* choice.  The suggestion is that questions should be phrased instead in terms of objective details, which is exactly what this question does.  I'm voting to leave it open.

Comment: Why can't you drink your own beer at the airport?

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica Swedish laws prevent consumption of your own alcohol in public and at places that sell alcohol. The only exception is hotels.

Comment: Very simple, if you do not agree with the price of beer you do not drink beer, works everywhere.

Comment: @Willeke: That's clear, but what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: I tend to search for "cheap beer in [area/airport]" pretty often, sometimes you find a forum thread that hasn't been active in 15 years...

Comment: @guest, that I myself can not see the value of this question and answer. No beer is cheapest.

Comment: Yes, no beer is cheapest but still beer drinkers might want to find the cheapest beer. There is no contradiction in that. I could say "I drink no beer under 7€". Then the question is valueable: If you know what the cheapest beer is I can decide if I drink it or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frequent travellers of Arlanda Airport, as well as airport staff, all know the cheapest beer at Arlanda can be found at McDonald's in Skycity.

One large beer at McDonald's is 65:- (5.5€).

McDonald's and Skycity can be found in the departures area, before security, between terminal 4 and 5, it's a quick walk from all terminals. If you're in terminal 2 you can take the Arlanda Express for free between the south and north station.

Why is this special? [It's the only McDonald's in Sweden with right to sell alcohol](https://www.thelocal.se/20090313/18204).

*Keep in mind that it can take 25 minutes to pass the security and get to the gate and that the gates usually close 30 minutes before the departure time, so leave at least 1 hour before departure.*